# Text Based Configuration Manager for Linux

Tags: linux, chef-infra, ansible, puppet, orchestration

Is there a tool similar to Ansible / Chef / Puppet to manage the configuration of a single instance / machine which keeps all setting in one place?

I'm thinking of some kind of text based configuration manager where you can put your settings into text files and apply all settings by issuing one command.

I really like the way Ansible works: Everything is nicely structured in yaml files and you can configure all sorts of dependencies / tasks / templates etc..

All of the above tools offer the possibility to run the client and server part on the same machine, but all were built to deploy settings on a large number or group of machines which seems to be overkill for this purpose. **Or am I wrong**?

Answer (score 5):

You are wrong. Those tools are totally fine also for managing your workstation, all (Chef, Puppet, Ansible) also have a mode to work without any server/master - AFAIK Ansible even has no such thing at all.

Comment: There is [ansible-pull](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/playbooks_intro.html#ansible-pull) but I think that's rarely used. But I totally agree. I have seen many folks setting up their local development environment with Ansible.

Answer (score 1):

Ansible works well for this task. A method that I have found works well is to setup a default inventory file and utilize the [non-ssh connection type](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/intro_inventory.html#non-ssh-connection-types) 'local' and it takes the command

`ansible-playbook -i /path/to/inventory playbook.yml`

down to

`ansible-playbook playbook.yml`

### The Setup

**Setting up the default [inventory](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/intro_inventory.html) file**

In */etc/ansible/hosts* add an entry for localhost like so:

```
localhost ansible_connection=local
```